# Cannot register REST services

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I try to register a directory as a REST app in my CFIDE administrator:

> Error registering REST service. Please ensure that you have entered a
>   proper mapping and path. Application servizi could not be initialized.
>   Reason: The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs. The
>   application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.

My directory contains:

Application.cfc

```
component output="false"
{
    this.name = "otticanet-rest";
    this.applicationTimeout = createTimespan(0,1,0,0);
    this.datasource = "svvv";

    this.restsettings.skipCFCWithError = true;

    public boolean function onRequestStart()
    {       
        return true;
    }
}
```

Product.cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="occhiali">

    <cffunction name="getByMarchioAndTipo"
                access="remote"
                httpmethod="GET"
                restpath="{idmarchio}/{idtipo}"
                returntype="Struct"
                produces="application/json">

        <cfargument name="marchio" required="true" restargsource="Path" type="numeric" />
        <cfargument name="tipo" required="true" restargsource="Path" type="numeric" />

        <cfreturn LOCAL.s />
    </cffunction>   
...
```

So what?

In addition, this worked a month ago. What can be happened?

Comment: If it was working before, what has changed?  Did any of the code change?  Was the server patched/upgraded?  Have any of the folders been renamed/moved?

Comment: no changes + all is still in place

Comment: VERY rarely does code "just stop working". You have to figure out what changed.  Something changed, a permission, something got patched/upgraded/moved something.  EVERY time I had code working then stopped, even though I was sure nothing was different, I found something had changed.  A function was added to the component, OS got patched something else obscure.

Comment: +1 on @Lance comment and I would just add that sometimes a server reboot will get you too because it enables a change that had been lying in wait until the reboot.

Comment: rebooted. nothing changed :(( Can you please tell me if above configuration is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *skipCFCWithError*  is true and there is some problem in only CFC present in that directory then it shows this error.
Probably you might have changed something in this CFC and its not working now.
Try to access your CFC in browser just as you access any CFM.
That will tell you if there is a problem in your CFC or not.

If there is a problem then fix it and try again.