# Coldfusion RESTful webservice: Object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: web-services, rest, coldfusion, cfml

When I call the URL `http://192.168.2.26:8080/rest/RestSample/season/1.json` I get the error:

> "Error","ajp-bio-8012-exec-4","03/01/13","16:51:58","RestSample","object is not an instance of declaring class The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\path_to\api\service.cfc'' "

This is the `/api/service.cfc` file:

```
<cfscript>
component restpath="season" rest="true"
{

    remote query function getSeasonsByUserId(numeric userid restargsource="Path") httpmethod="GET" restpath="{userid}"
    {
        var response = "";
        var qry = new Query();
        var userQry = "";

        qry.setSQl("select * from mytable where userID = :userid");
        qry.addParam(name="userid", value="#arguments.userid#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric");
        userQry = qry.execute().getResult();

        if(userQry.recordcount == 0)
        {
            response = userQry;
        } else {
            throw(type="Restsample.SeasonsNotFoundError", errorCode='404', detail='Seasons not found');
        }

        return response;
    }    
}   
</cfscript>
```

**Edit #1**: following this tutorial:
http://www.anujgakhar.com/2012/02/20/using-rest-services-in-coldfusion-10/

**Edit #2**: my application.cfc

```
<cfscript>
component output="false"
{
    this.name = "RestSample";
    this.applicationTimeout = createTimespan(0,0,0,0);
    this.datasource = "mydsn";
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";

    //this.restsettings.skipCFCWithError = true;

    public boolean function onRequestStart()
    {
        restInitApplication(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()), this.name);

        return true;
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

Also would like to note, refreshing REST services in the admin ALWAYS gives me the following message:

```
Unable to refresh REST service.
Application RestSample could not be initialized.
Reason: The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
```

However, I can remove them and add them via the onRequestStart() without any problems.

**Edit #3**

My current structure

/api/main/service.cfc
/api/application.cfc
/api/index.cfm

application.cfc

```
<cfscript>
component output="false"
{
    this.name = "RestSample";
    this.applicationTimeout = createTimespan(0,0,0,0);
    this.datasource = "mydsn";
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";

    this.restsettings.skipCFCWithError = true;

    public boolean function onRequestStart()
    {
        restInitApplication(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()).concat("main\"), this.name);

        return true;
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

service.cfc

```
<cfscript>
component restpath="season" rest="true"
{

    remote Query function getSeasonsByUserId(numeric userid restargsource="Path") httpmethod="GET" restpath="{userid}"
    {
        var response = "";
        var qry = new Query();
        var userQry = "";

        qry.setSQl("select * from mytable where userID = :userid");
        qry.addParam(name="userid", value="#arguments.userid#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric");
        userQry = qry.execute().getResult();

        return userQry;
    } 
}   
</cfscript>
```

I still get the following error:

```
'object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Comment: I haven't worked with CF's REST implementation, but should that throw be a [RestSetResponse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS38f7811c62cc227c71c3c3dd135155ecceb-8000.html) instead?

Comment: @PeterBoughton I don't think so... my mapping is RestSample, thus it should be RestSample too? To be honest, I was following a tutorial on this one.

Comment: The first step to diagnosing the problem is identifying where the error is coming from. Remove (or comment out) the if and change return to `return userQry;` to see if that's where the error is at all. (p.s. the `== 0` is back to front and unnecessary anyway.)

Comment: Include the link to the tutorial in the question - that way it can be checked if you've misunderstood the instructions or if the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I got rid of the if statement, and returned the query (after having removed the rest service from the administration console and re-adding it)... same error.

Comment: Ok, well that suggests it wasn't what I thought it was. Will have to wait for someone who's actually used the REST stuff to help.

Comment: I searched for the error message and found this: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3346117 - so check if your App.cfc has `restInitApplication` outside of any functions (the tutorial has it in onRequestStart so if you've got the same as that then it's probably something else).

Comment: That error _"The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs"_ was in another question recently - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499275/cannot-register-rest-services

Comment: There also seems to be a CF bug relating to using `/* comments */` in REST CFCs :/ https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3119366

Comment: @PeterBoughton I removed my comments, error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the files under `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot` (instead of the site's IIS root) and was able to register the REST service via the administration console without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start a little simpler example and see if you can get to a working state. I've successfully set up a working REST service by following these steps:

Go to REST Services in your ColdFusion Administrator and remove any existing REST registrations.

In a new directory in your web root, create Application.cfc with the following content (note that the `<cfscript>` tags are not necessary if you're on CF 9 or above):

```
component output="false"
{
    this.name = "RestSample";
}
```

In the same directory, create index.cfm with the following content:

```
<cfset restInitApplication(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()), "RestSample") />
Done.
```

In the same directory, create service.cfc with the following content:

```
component restpath="season" rest="true"
{
    remote struct function getSeasonsByUserId(numeric userid restargsource="Path") httpmethod="GET" restpath="{userid}"
    {
        return {
            'hello': 'world'    
        };
    } 
}
```

First, browse to the index.cfm through your browser and verify that you see the text 'Done.'

Open REST Services in ColdFusion Administrator and verify that you see the REST service has been registered successfully.

Finally, browse to the REST resource in your browser via /rest/RestSample/season/123 and hopefully you'll see the trusty "hello world".

Let me know if you still have troubles and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Also note (as discussed in the comments of the tutorial you're following), you'll have to create an index.cfm to hit in order to refresh the REST service.

Comment: I had the index.cfm and I applied your fix. I still get the same problem.

Comment: I replicated your files, here's what I'm getting: "Error","ajp-bio-8012-exec-10","03/06/13","13:01:51",,"'' The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' "

Comment: Wow. I'm very impressed with your determination to get this working. I would have picked up Taffy by now if I were you. I don't know what the error you're getting means. When do you get that error and how does it present itself? Have you looked through your error logs to see if you can find more detail? Have you restarted CF since you started having troubles?

Comment: I tried this setup on Win7 Pro, with CF10 by itself and it works. I wonder why it doesn't work on my VM. In the meantime, I've simply created a page that outputs JSON and I have the process that needed it use this instead. I haven't restarted, I'll try that later today. Logs show what I've put up, not much else.