# Cannot add the most basic RESTful web service

Tags: web-services, rest, coldfusion

I'm on Windows 2008 R2 (64-bit) using CF10 (64-bit) (developer edition?)

I am trying to implement this very basic tutorial:
http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/rest-support-in-coldfusion-part-i

I created a new website through IIS on port 8081 and then added two files:

/index.cfm (in theory, since no application.cfc containing app vars was needed, I could have skipped this)

```
<cfset s = "Hello World!">
<cfoutput>#s#</cfoutput>
```

/RestExample/HelloWorld.cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restPath="/hello">
        <cffunction name="sayHello" access="remote" returnType="String" httpMethod="GET">
                 <cfset res="Hello World">
                 <cfreturn res>
        </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

In CF Admin:

- Root Path: `C:/websites/test/RestExample/`
- Service Mapping: `Example`

I get the following error:

```
Error registering REST service. Please ensure that you have entered a proper mapping and path.
Application Example could not be initialized.
Reason: The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
```

A bit of system information:

```
Server Product  ColdFusion  
Version  10,0,8,284032  
Tomcat Version  7.0.23.0  
Edition  Developer    
Serial Number  Developer    
Operating System  Windows Server 2008 R2    
OS Version  6.1    
Update Level  /C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib/updates/chf10000008.jar    
Adobe Driver Version  4.1 (Build 0001)    
JVM Details  
Java Version  1.6.0_29    
Java Vendor  Sun Microsystems Inc.    
Java Vendor URL  http://java.sun.com/  
Java Home  C:\ColdFusion10\jre
```

Not sure if it's a configuration issue at this point? This is [related to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166822/coldfusion-restful-webservice-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class), and trying to simplify everything to isolate the cause.

**Edit #1**
I was able to add a this very simple RESTful service to a Windows 7 64-bit / CF 10 (no updates) without any issues. I wonder if it's my install that is corrupt or the update that corrupted it?

**Edit #2**
I reinstalled my CF server and it still gave me the same issue.

**Edit #3**

As per milanchandna's suggestions, I followed these steps:

1. Created a folder c:\websites\milanchandna
2. Created a new website (milanchandna using the apppool with the same name) in IIS and used c:\websites\milanchandna as root, running on port 8084
3. Created jakarta virtual directory (need this)
4. Added basic HelloWorld.cfc
5. Navigated to HelloWorld.cfc with success, no errors
6. In CF Admin, REST Services, added the following:
7. Root Path: C:/websites/milanchandna/
8. Service mapping: Example
9. Click Add Service
10. Get error: 
    Error registering REST service. Please ensure that you have entered a proper mapping and path.
    Application Example could not be initialized.
    Reason: The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
    The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.

HelloWorld.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restPath="/hello">
        <cffunction name="sayHello" access="remote" returnType="String" httpMethod="GET">
                 <cfset res="Hello World">
                 <cfreturn res>
        </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the files under C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot (instead of the site's IIS root) and was able to register the REST service via the administration console without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a basic example not working, I will suggest to follow it from starting.

1. Create a fresh new folder in IIS webroot. This should not be inside any folder already being used for CF REST.
2. Just put one simple rest cfc in this folder and nothing else. The CFC example given in your problem description looks good, let's use that.
3. Access this CFC from browser as you would access any cfm

   eg:[http://mysite:8081/mypath_to_cfc/mycfc.cfc]
4. Check if this throws any error. If it does, then there is a problem in CFC. If it doesn't then you are good to go.
5. Register this folder as REST application from administrator.